# serializability in SQL transaction

Tags: sql

Assume T1 and T2 are SQL transactions. What are the final values of A and B after each transaction is performed?

A   is  supposed    to  be  less    than    B.      Initially   A   is  0   and B   is  100.
– T1    reads   original    A   and B   values, and changes A   to  60.
– T2    reads   original        A   and B   values, and changes B   to  20.
– Transactions  T1  and T2  both    maintained  the consistency condition   “A  <   B”  … but   what    are the final   values  of  A   and B?
– Could this    happen  with    Serializability?

Even though T1 and T2 both maintained the consistency condition, I think that this problem is detected inside transaction T2 and therefore t2 is aborted. I think the final values are 60 and 100. Is that correct? can you someone provide more insight?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if A and B are columns or variables. The following applies if A and B are columns.

T2 will not be able to update table until T1 commits its transaction. At that stage A = 60. If *consistency condition* is enforced by a `CONSTRAINT` then the update in T2 will fail.